# is there any tool to show hierarchy of devices in Linux?

Tags: linux, sysfs

I want to see a tree-like structure of all devices in Linux. In Windows, I can use [Device Manager](https://www.howtogeek.com/167094/how-to-use-the-windows-device-manager-for-troubleshooting/) with "show by connection". BSD systems report such data to [dmesg](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dmesg&sektion=8) in format "child at parent" and have utilities such as [`devinfo`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=devinfo&sektion=8), so it is easy to understand relations between devices.

In Linux this information is stored in `/sys`, but its format is not user friendly.

I can query each bus with `lspci`, `lsusb`, `lsscsi` etc, but is there something I can use to recreate full device hierarchy?  `lshw` shows bus information but not devices.

Comment: How about `lshw` ?

Comment: Thanks @Atul . It looks good, but it seems that it shows only buses, it least for my installation. I see PCI host, I see USB and SATA controllers on it, but it does not show usb devices nor ``sda`` on my SATA..

Comment: how about `lsblk`?

Comment: How about a small script for showing the rest using `lspci` and `lsblk`

Comment: I can combine ``lshw``, ``lspci``, ``lsusb``, ``lsscsi`` and ``lsblk``, but I wonder if there are some ready-to-use tools :)

Comment: I think the above segregates the devices and help isolate the same too for viewing and troubleshooting.

 I cant think of something which is combination of all above on top of my head, may be someone else can suggest alternative(s)

Comment: Add `dmidecode` to the list. Also `lscpu`.

Comment: @user996142 - `lshw` shows all my block-devices (SATA and USB) and keyboard/mouse. Not sure why yours wouldn't.

Comment: @user996142 about block devices missing: I'd guess it's because you didn't execute `lshw` as root. It shows a warning upon execution though, where it says that the output will be incomplete unless it's executed with root permissions.

Answer (score 0):

`lshw`-based utilities will provide you with such output. For complete output execute it as root.

Most likely you'll want `gtk-lshw`. On my system it looks like this:

[image: gtk-lshw]

Here you can see various entities *(such as **USB controller**, **PCI bridge**)* are written in **bold** and have a mark, meaning they contain sub-entities that you can descend into with double-click.

You can also execute `sudo lshw -html > /tmp/devices.html` and then open the html file in a browser, though  currently *(as of version `B.02.18`)* it's inconveniently designed.

**Note**: there's a small bug in that `L1`, `L2`, `L3` caches are shown as if they belong to the motherboard, whereas they are actually a part of CPU. Other than that, the tree looks valid.